# Разные цвета в Ie11 и браузерах на chromium. Есть ли решение?

Tags: вёрстка, internet-explorer, кроссбраузерность

Прошу опытных фронт-енд разработчиков помочь с такими странностями:

1. Можно ли оставлять цвета такие, какие по макету(они же видны с левой стороны изображения в google). Справа находится ie11. Один цвет по макету, но настолько разный в браузерах. Это нужно как то исправлять?
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну это проблема решается просто вставкой изображения ...тогда 100% отображаться будет одинакого

Comment: @MaximLensky такое себе решение)) ТС, вы бы хоть код привели для тестирования

Comment: @DaemonHK  https://www.dropbox.com/s/bql6msrvuwg33re/2019-04-17_044954.png два браузера видно сразу

Comment: ТС, попробуйте НЕ использовать rgba()